# Ayuda con una tabla en html

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

estoy haciendo el codigo html con ayuda del dompdf para exportarlo a pdf pero al agregar una tabla no me carga bien la tabla y no puedo cuadrarla

Adjunto el codigo de la tabla

```html
<table border="1"  cellpadding="0" width="230" height="50">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="100" rowspan="4">
                <p>
                    <img
                        width="100"
                        height="94"
                        src="file:///C:/Users/ASESOR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/09/clip_image002.png"
                    />
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="270">
                <p align="center">
                    PROCESO DE GESTIÓN DE RECURSOS
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102">
                <p align="center">
                    CÓDIGO
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="111" colspan="3">
                <p align="center">
                    FSW-100
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="270">
                <p align="center">
                    <strong>DEPARTAMENTO DE LAS TIC</strong>
                    <strong></strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102" rowspan="2">
                <p align="center">
                    VERSIÓN 1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="111" colspan="3" rowspan="2">
                <p align="center">
                    01-12-17
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="270">
                <p align="center">
                    Tecnologías de la información y las comunicaciones
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="270">
                <p align="center">
                    <strong>Acta de Entrega</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="102">
                <p align="center">
                    PAGINA
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="31">
                <p align="center">
                    1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="46">
                <p align="center">
                    DE
                </p>
            </td>
            <td width="32">
                <p align="center">
                    2
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

agradeceria la ayuda asi es como queda el pdf y necesito cuadrarlo para que quede centrado y bien ajustado

gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y cual es la diferencia?

Comment: que no queda centrado y queda desigual

Comment: Puedes trabajar los estilos con porcentajes, es mas dinamico

Comment: Y si tratas de cambiar las dimensiones de la hoja ? $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

Comment: si pero igual no se porque no me deja ajustarlo bien

Comment: se me va al **** lo demas ya lo tenia con land scape pero el texto que daba muy ancho para las especificaiones del formato